# Cloud9, use previous version of LESS compiler

Tags: npm, less, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to downgrade to a previous version of the LESS compiler, an update is causing my program to crash. I can't figure out how to do this... I've done `npm install -g less@2.5.2` however when I run `lessc -v` it returns 2.6.0 again...

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for a while, I finally stumbled upon this: https://docs.c9.io/docs/installing-npm-modules

The global flag does not actually work as I had previously thought it did on Cloud9 (due to their security implementations). The command must be used within the project folder itself.

Comment: I think that document is talking about something else (as in global installs don't mean that your package is installed on __all__ your workspaces). Your version should have downgraded with `-g` too. I wonder if running `npm remove -g less` and then `npm install -g less@2.5.2` would work?

Comment: I did try that previously, but I was doing it _outside_ of the project folder (I'm running multiple projects). Doing as you describe _inside_ the project folder, did resolve this problem for me. I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I needed ones to downgrade lessc to an old version and it did not work for me straight forward

> the problem was because `npm install` differs from `sudo npm install`

now to fix the problem walkthrough with me, but I not sure if non-linux users can do the same, even though simply `sudo` is the same as `run as administrator`

1. uninstall `less` using `npm uninstall -g less --save`

   - I actually used `whereis less` to find it, then `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less`
2. install the wanted version of less using `sudo npm install -g less@1.6.3`
3. check lessc version using `lessc -v`

hope this helps and

happy maintaining legacy apps